# react-native: Updating an element in the setstate array does not re-render the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was trying to update an array in setstate and want to render child component based on the update.

Initial state:

```
state={selectAdress: []};
```

componentDidMount:

```
const selectAdress = [];
    if (addresses.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
            selectAdress.push(false);
        }
        this.setState({ selectAdress: selectAdress });
    }
```

Method:

```
const selectAdress = this.state.selectAdress.slice();

        for (i = 0; i < selectAdress.length; i++) {
            if (i === index) {
                selectAdress[index] = !this.state.selectAdress[index];
            }
            else {
                selectAdress[i] = false;
            }
        }
        this.setState({ selectAdress: selectAdress }, () => {
            console.log(this.state, '787878787878778787')
           });
```

Render code in the main component:

```
render() {
        const { selectAdress } = this.state
        console.log(this.state);
        return (
            <AddressComponent
                updateAddressCheckbox={this.updateAddressCheckbox}
                onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
                selectAdress={selectAdress} />
        );
    }
```

Render Code in the child component:

```
const selectAdress = propsObj.selectAdress;

    return (
            <View style={{ height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 85 }}>
                <FlatList
                    data={addresses}
                    keyExtractor={(x,i) => i.toString()}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => <View style={styles.container}>
                        <CheckBox
                            title={null}
                            checkedIcon='check-square-o'
                            uncheckedIcon='square-o'
                            checked={selectAdress[index]}
                            onPress={() => propsObj.updateAddressCheckbox(index)} />
```

I tried many answers from stack overflow. But nothing is allowing me to re-render the component. However, the state is clearly updating if i check the logs.
can someone help me out with what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you also put up your `render()` code so we can see the template syntax you're calling?

Comment: updated render code.

Comment: Update `<View style={styles.container}>` to `<View style={styles.container} key={index}>`

Comment: tried that. but the re-render is not happening. console.log for the child component does not print which tells me it's not rendering again after I change the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Adding extraData property of FlatList, i was able to resolve the issue.

```
return (
            <View style={{ height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 85 }}>
                <FlatList
                    extraData={propsObj}
                    data={addresses}
                    keyExtractor={(x,i) => i.toString()}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => <View style={styles.container}>
                        <CheckBox
                            title={null}
                            checkedIcon='check-square-o'
                            uncheckedIcon='square-o'
                            checked={selectAdress[index]}
                            onPress={() => propsObj.updateAddressCheckbox(index)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems that you're pulling the info for `selectAdress` from props instead of state:

```
const selectAdress = propsObj.selectAdress;
```

You should try changing it to use this instead:

```
const { selectAdress } = this.state;
```

Side-note: address should be spelt with 2 d's. You did this correctly in other variables (e.g. `updateAddressCheckbox`) so you should update it to `selectAddress` for consistency.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i am passing selectAdress as prop to child component. If you see the render method in parent component, i did the same. Thanks for the sidenote. will do that.

Comment: Does the props update when passed down? You verified that the state updates but not necessarily the props.

Comment: Thanks. I found out the real issue being with FlatList. I used extradata property which solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since `selectAdress` is not part of the `data` (`addresses`), you need to add `extraData={propsObj.selectAdress}`.